# How to reshape numpy array keeping each nth element

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of shape, say, `(1000, 80)` and I want to convert it to `(100, 40, 2)`. You can think of it as having 1000 observations where the first 40 columns refer to a specific feature across 40 days and the next 40 columns to a 2nd feature across the same 40 days.

So, I want to the 2nd dimension to be the 40 days while the 3rd should be the values of these two features for each day.

Here's a simple example with what I tried:

```
import numpy as np

data = [[11, 22, 33, 44],
        [55, 66, 77 ,88],
        [99, 100, 101, 102]]
data = np.array(data)

# This works but I have to manually do it for every day
np.c_[data[:, ::2], data[:, 1::2]].reshape((3, 2, 2))

# This does not work
np.c_[data[:, i::2] for i in range(2)].reshape((3, 2, 2))
```

Desired output:

```
array([[[ 11,  33],
    [ 22,  44]],
    [[ 55,  77],
     [ 66,  88]],
    [[ 99, 101],
     [100, 102]]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `reshape` first and then transpose the second and third axis:

```
data.reshape(-1, 2, data.shape[1] / 2).transpose(0,2,1)
#array([[[ 11,  33],
#        [ 22,  44]],

#       [[ 55,  77],
#        [ 66,  88]],

#       [[ 99, 101],
#        [100, 102]]])
```

Or `swapaxes`:

```
data.reshape(-1, 2, data.shape[1] / 2).swapaxes(1,2)
#array([[[ 11,  33],
#        [ 22,  44]],

#       [[ 55,  77],
#        [ 66,  88]],

#       [[ 99, 101],
#        [100, 102]]])
```

Or as @wwii commented, `reshape` with `column-major` order:

```
data.reshape(-1, data.shape[1] / 2, 2, order='F')
```

Comment: I get a TypeError unless I use `data.shape[1] // 2` - ??

Comment: Do you have to swap axes because reshape defaults to `row-major` order?  Is there a reason you didn't use `order='F'`? I don't see people using that often here on SO.

Comment: @wwii Yes you're right `order='F'` should also work here and is a great option.